# Adding link to Mongo DB when uploading image to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

In my Express backend, I have set up a connection with S3 Bucket for uploading images, and it works.
However additionally, I would like to be able to store a reference link (S3 url) of the saved image in my Mongo Database.

I have been trying to play around with req.file object but somehow, I cannot get the req.file.location, whereas req.file.buffer works okay (as in the example below in itemController.js). Is there any problem in my s3.js configuration? Or pehraps I would need a different approach to get req.file.location instead of buffer?

Below my bucket configuration **s3.js**

```js
// s3.js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

// s3 bucket configuration
const awsConfig = {
    accessKeyid : process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey : process.env.S3_ACCESS_SECRET,
    region : process.env.S3_REGION
  }
  const S3 = new AWS.S3(awsConfig)
  
  //s3 bucket upload function
  const uploadToS3 = (fileData) => {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) =>{
      const params = {
        Bucket : process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: `${Date.now().toString()}.jpg`,
        Body: fileData 
      }
        S3.upload(params, (err, data) =>{
          if(err){
            console.log(err)
            reject(err)
          }
          console.log(data)
          return resolve(data)
        })
  
    })
  }
  
  module.exports = {
    uploadToS3
  }
```

Here is my **itemController.js**

```js
const Item = require('../models/itemModel')
const Worker = require('../models/workerModel')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const multer = require('multer')
const { uploadToS3 } = require('../s3')

//! Multer configuration
const multerConfig = {
  limits: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, done) {
    if (file.mimetype === "image/jpg"|| file.mimetype === "image/png" || file.mimetype ==='image/jpeg') {
      done(null, true)
    } else {
      done("Niewłaściwy plik, użyj .jpg .jpeg .png", false)
    }
  }
}
const upload = multer(multerConfig)



//! CREATE new item 
const createItem = async (req, res) => {
  // multer middleware that handles file upload
  upload.single("image")(req, res, async () => {
    //destructuring form req.body
    const {
      title,
      model,
      producer,
      serialNumber,
      yearOfProduction,
      atEmployee,
      seller,
      warrantyDate,
      purchaseDate,
      image,
    } = req.body

    if (!title){
      return res.status(400).json({error:'Błąd! Wymagane jest podanie chociaż nazwy narzędzia.'})
    }

    //try-catch to create new Item and catch error. Add "await" because of "async" - Js promise above
    try {
      const item = await Item.create({
        title,
        model,
        producer,
        serialNumber,
        yearOfProduction,
        atEmployee,
        seller,
        warrantyDate,
        purchaseDate,
        image: req.file ? req.file.buffer : image,
      })

      if (req.file) {
        // upload file to S3 and store the URL in the database
        const result = await uploadToS3(req.file.buffer)
        item.imageUrl = result.location
        await item.save()
      }

      res.status(200).json(item)
    } catch(error) {
      res.status(400).json({error: error.message})
    }
  })
}
...
```

And here is my **ItemModel.js**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

//mongoose function to create new model Schema
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const itemSchema = new Schema ({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    producer: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    model: { 
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    serialNumber: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    yearOfProduction:{
        type: Number,
        required: false
    },
    seller:{
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    purchaseDate: { 
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    warrantyDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: false,
    },
    //Linking Worker model to an Item
    atEmployee: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: false,
        ref:'Worker',
    },

    image: {
        type: String,
        required: false, 
    }

}, { timestamps: true })

module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema)
```

Comment: This is how I actually solved it:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I actually solved it

**itemController.js**

```js
const Item = require('../models/itemModel')
const Worker = require('../models/workerModel')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const multer = require('multer')
const { uploadToS3 } = require('../s3')

//! Multer configuration
const multerConfig = {
  limits: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, done) {
    if (file.mimetype === "image/jpg"|| file.mimetype === "image/png" || file.mimetype ==='image/jpeg') {
      done(null, true)
    } else {
      done("Niewłaściwy plik, użyj .jpg .jpeg .png", false)
    }
  }
}
const upload = multer(multerConfig)



//! CREATE new item 
const createItem = async (req, res) => {
  // multer middleware that handles file upload
  upload.single("image")(req, res, async () => {
    //destructuring form req.body
    const {
      title,
      model,
      producer,
      serialNumber,
      yearOfProduction,
      atEmployee,
      seller,
      warrantyDate,
      purchaseDate,
      image,
    } = req.body

    if (!title){
      return res.status(400).json({error:'Błąd! Wymagane jest podanie chociaż nazwy narzędzia.'})
    }

    //try-catch to create new Item and catch error. Add "await" because of "async" - Js promise above
    try {
      let item = {}
      if (req.file) {
        // upload file to S3 and store the URL in the database if image has been uploaded
        const result = await uploadToS3(req.file.buffer)
        item = await Item.create({
          title,
          model,
          producer,
          serialNumber,
          yearOfProduction,
          atEmployee,
          seller,
          warrantyDate,
          purchaseDate,
          image: result.Location,
        })
        //if no image, show nothing
      } else {
        item = await Item.create({
          title,
          model,
          producer,
          serialNumber,
          yearOfProduction,
          atEmployee,
          seller,
          warrantyDate,
          purchaseDate,
        })
      }

      res.status(200).json(item)
    } catch(error) {
      res.status(400).json({error: error.message})
    }
  })
}
```